# Creating multiple ec2 aws instances and attaching multiple networking interfaces with specific IP using (count, for_each) Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I am unable to implement the creation of multiple instances with a attached multiple network interface. I have a code where three instances are created and 3 network interfaces are attached. I would like to do this using count, for_each. I could no5 find implemented methods on the Internet. I ask you to help me how to implement the code using count

```
resource "aws_network_interface" "private_elasticsearch" {
subnet_id       = aws_subnet.private_subnets.id


private_ips     = ["10.245.10.6"]
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.elastic_traffic.id, 
  aws_security_group.general.id]
  tags = {
    Environment = "Test"
    Project = "test"
    Name = "elasticsearch-interface"
  }
}


resource "aws_network_interface" "private_elasticsearch2" {
  subnet_id       = aws_subnet.private_subnets.id
  private_ips     = ["10.245.10.7"]
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.elastic_traffic.id, aws_security_group.general.id]
  tags = {
    Environment = "Test"
    Project = "test"
    Name = "elasticsearch-interface2"
  }
}


resource "aws_network_interface" "private_elasticsearch3" {
  subnet_id       = aws_subnet.private_subnets.id
  private_ips     = ["10.245.10.8"]
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.elastic_traffic.id, aws_security_group.general.id]
  tags = {
    Environment = "Test"
    Project = "test"
    Name = "elasticsearch-interface3"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "dev-elasticsearch" {
  ami = "ami-08bdc08970fcbd34a"
  availability_zone = "eu-north-1a"
  instance_type =  "t3.micro"
  network_interface {
     device_index=0
     network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.private_elasticsearch.id
  }
  tags = {
    Environment = "Test"
    Project = "test"
    Name = "elasticsearch-instance-dev"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "dev-elasticsearch-2" {
  ami = "ami-08bdc08970fcbd34a"
  availability_zone = "eu-north-1a"
  instance_type = "t3.micro"
  network_interface {
     device_index=0
     network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.private_elasticsearch2.id
  }
  tags = {
    Environment = "Test"
    Project = "test"
    Name = "elasticsearch-instance-dev-2"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "dev-elasticsearch-3" {
  ami = "ami-08bdc08970fcbd34a"
  availability_zone = "eu-north-1a"
  instance_type = "t3.micro"
  network_interface {
     device_index=0
     network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.private_elasticsearch3.id
}
  tags = {
    Environment = "Test"
    Project = "test"
    Name = "elasticsearch-instance-dev-3"
  }
```

Comment: First you have to explain what's wrong with the current code? Any errors?

Comment: There are no errors, but I can understand how to implement it using count or for_each

Comment: I need to get rid of such a long code, and minimize the code entry, thereby optimizing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `count` (`for_each` also possible):

```
locals {
    ips = ["10.245.10.6", "10.245.10.7", "10.245.10.8"]
}



resource "aws_network_interface" "private_elasticsearch" {

  count           = length(local.ips)

  subnet_id       = aws_subnet.private_subnets.id
  private_ips     = [local.ips[count.index]]
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.elastic_traffic.id, 
                     aws_security_group.general.id]
  tags = {
    Environment = "Test"
    Project = "test"
    Name = "elasticsearch-interface${count.index}"
  }
}


resource "aws_instance" "dev-elasticsearch" {

  count           = length(local.ips)  

  ami = "ami-08bdc08970fcbd34a"
  availability_zone = "eu-north-1a"
  instance_type =  "t3.micro"
  network_interface {
     device_index=0
     network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.private_elasticsearch[count.index].id
  }
  tags = {
    Environment = "Test"
    Project = "test"
    Name = "elasticsearch-instance-dev${count.index}"
  }
}
```

Comment: in resource "aws_network_interface" "private_elasticsearch":
12:   private_ips     = [local.ips[each.index]]
The "each" object does not have an attribute named "index". The supported attributes are each.key and each.value, the current key and value
pair of the "for_each" attribute set.

Comment: @ЗаманбекМаксутбеков Sorry, for that. Corrected the answer.